# Creating BaseAdapter for GridView android

Tags: android

Basically i need to create:
check box on left and image view on right. Something like this:

[image]

These combination in portrait should be 3xN, N is int of row count. For this i thought would be good to use Grid View, but i don't have much experience with Grids. So i started to write adapters:

I got this method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    CheckBox check = null;
    ImageView pic = null;

    LinearLayout view = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    view.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        check = new CheckBox(mContext);
        check.setTag(position);

        view.addView(check); 

        pic = new ImageView(mContext);
        pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_star);

        view.addView(pic); 


    return view;
}
```

and maybe there i should create one View of check box and image View. This worked but image is lower than check box, how to make them in one line ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create seperate Layout for griview content

For eg: `gridview_custom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:gravity="center">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now create Custom Adapter for your `GridView` and override `getView()`

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView; 
     CheckBox check = null;
             ImageView pic = null;


    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                // attributes
    LayoutInflater vi = 
            (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.gridview_custom, null);
     } 

    pic = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    check = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    return v;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the layout is a fixed one, it would be easier to specify the layout in an XML file and use it to create the view.  You should be using a `HORIZONTAL` orientation, though. And also take care of re-using the view (a re-usable instance is passed to you in the `convertView` parameter. Use it if it is not `null`).

Answer (score 0):

Don't add a checkbox and an image dynamically. Instead what you can do is, create an XML file that will contain a checkbox and an ImageView with horizontal orientation as you require, the getView function will be like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if (CONTEXT != null) {


        final LayoutInflater lInflater = (LayoutInflater) CONTEXT
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_xml, null);
        final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view
                .findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        final ImageView ivIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
        ivIcon.setImageResource(A.this.getResources().getDrawables(R.id.image));
        return view;
        }
        else {
        return null;
        }
}
```

Thank you :)